# BCM4311 - No option to enable Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot see any wifi enabling option. I have selected the Broadcom driver in software and update, and the Wi-Fi switch is enabled in the BIOS.

I've looked through the help pages and run the following:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:efdfc000-efdfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1d:09:b6:10:83
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.135 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff*
```

What should I do?

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

Comment: Thanks, done that for my BC card as detailed but still don't see any option for wifi enablement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. And also describe what did you do?

Comment: And what you did? Installed a wrong `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver?

Comment: Installed the one that was identified in the article for the BC card

Comment: Which one did you install?

Answer (score 5):

Connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

Comment: Brilliant, I can see them now. Thanks for your help.....

Comment: @lanb Had you followed the instructions in the duplicate answer this is exactly what you would be doing. It clearly says `firmware-b43-installer` for all 14e4:4311 revisions and irrespective of the Ubuntu release. Why then did you installed the wrong driver?

Comment: The problem was that OP installed a wrong driver using GUI, then `b43` was blacklisted. Maybe they installed the correct one.

Comment: @MichaelBay Yes, I followed the instructions and installed the firmware-b43-installer. Maybe what Pilot6 described above happened - I don't know, that's beyond my knowledge. Anyway, thanks again Pilot6

Comment: The correct answer.
Also, If you've got that `firmware-b43-installer` package was not found, please connect via cable ale do `sudo apt-get update` and then try again.