# HP 530/Intel celeron M, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS NO WIFI

Tags: wireless

I have tried every single step of the suggested solution mentioned for this issue, the main problem is that the commands didnt work :

Run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_015-9_amd64.deb
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.13
```

I did follow the commands on the link provided, but only one works the other two show the following:

```
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now tar: Child returned status 2 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now 
e@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$ sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o 
[sudo] password for e: 
Cannot open input file broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o e
@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$
```

The system Im using is 32bit using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The first one works, the next two bring as a result the above.

Can someone please help with this issue?still wifi doesnt even appear on this laptop.there is a button for the wifi which works immediately on windows but not linux ubuntu.

one update is :

e@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$ 
e@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$ sudo dpkg -i b43-fwcutter_019-2_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 214436 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack b43-fwcutter_019-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking b43-fwcutter (1:019-2) over (1:019-2) ...
Setting up b43-fwcutter (1:019-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
e@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$ 
e@e-HP-530-Notebook-PC-GU327AA-ABU:~$

also I dont know how to find which specific sub-model of HP 530 is it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

[BCM4311 - No option to enable Wi-Fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956698/bcm4311-no-option-to-enable-wi-fi)

problem sorted, thank you so much ideafix for your directions so that I could find the type of broadcom card etc